# Best way to gain access to more gpio pins on a raspberry pi 4

Tags: gpio

I am working on a project that requires the use of many gpio pins (ideally 100+). All those pins need to be able to do is turn on and off in a frequency of ~10hz. The only boards I was able to find allowed for ~40 gpio pins total and were the type of boards that completely cover the raspberry pi. Is there a device that e.g. uses i2c to set it's pin states?

Comment: You might like to try this: (1) "MCP23017 I2C Interface 16bit I/O Extension Module": 
https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32941624728.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.43143933PDxk2c&algo_pvid=27e137d2-2313-41c4-a034-576293f04060&algo_expid=27e137d2-2313-41c4-a034-576293f04060-0&btsid=0ab6f83115935265215004962ea4a3&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_,searchweb201603_. Cheers.

Comment: What are you connecting to at 10hz?

Comment: Does the frequency need to be precise? Then a GPIO pin (or I2C gpio expanders) won't do, because their accuracy is limited by the operating system's thread management and the bus usage. Depending on your job, you might need PWM pins instead (but getting 100 of those might be more challenging)

Answer (score 2):

I've not used one personally, but this should do the job: http://www.nationelectronics.com/raspberry-pi-extensions/174-raspberry-pi-hat-32-io-port-expander-v11-mcp23017-i2c-black-0648260628239.html

It does cover the whole Pi, but should only be using I²C to set the pin states (it is what they say) allowing you to use other pins yourself. You can stack them to give 128 extra GPIO with four boards.

If you are handy with a soldering iron then you could also build a separate board yourself with all eight ICs on and not cover the Pi if that is your requirement. I haven't searched, but you might even find someone selling a board with eight of these ICs in an existing design (it doesn't need to be Pi specific but will want a 3.3V I²C bus).

Answer (score 2):

Try the 74HC595 ([link here](https://learn.pimoroni.com/tutorial/170pt-projects/the-shift-register-170pt)) I have not used one myself, but have heard about them, I think it should work because my friend has used it successfully with an arduino.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a device that e.g. uses i2c to set it's pin states?

Yes, they are so called I2C expanders (already mentioned and linked on some other comments). For 100+ pins hovewer I strongly advise against branching them off a single Pi, I cannot really imagine how to route them for example in a building automation project.

Cool thing is I2C can be more or less easily extended to quite long cables, see:

1. [An overview](https://hackaday.com/2017/02/08/taking-the-leap-off-board-an-introduction-to-i2c-over-long-wires/) about the issues and some ICs you might find useful.
2. [A more detailed take](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/application-note/AN10658.pdf) at long-range i2c, just remark there is indeed a concrete business case for this

I used to have a few additional links but I can't quite find them right away. Perhaps I'll add in the future.